# EventListener 'drop' - get dropped elements id? - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, this, addeventlistener

I am trying to get the `id` of the *dragged* element. I saw a few examples for **JQuery**, but could not find a solutions for the **Vanilla** equivalent.
I tried it with `this`, however that seems to give me the document.

`event` will give me the dropped containers `id` instead.

```
let dropElements = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');

for (let item of dropElements) {
   item.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
   });
   item.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
       event.target.innerHTML = 'Woooop';
   });
}
```

I am thinking that maybe it is not intended to be able to have access to the dragged item, and i must get it via the i.e. `dragstart` eventlistener?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Comment: @Quentin `this` works now. However I stil can't get the dropped image. Basicly i rewrote the function to be a normal function, not an arrow function, which enabled `this` to work. But now `event.id == this.id`, which does not really help me, since I wanted the dropped <img>'s id.